# Law of total probability random variable proof

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, proof-writing

How would you prove the law of total probability for random variables?

The Theorem states:  Let $X: \Omega \mapsto S$ and $Y:\Omega \mapsto S'$ be random variables. Then, for all $ A\subseteq S', P (Y ∈ A) =\sum \nolimits_{
x∈X(Ω):P(X=x)>0}
P (Y ∈ A|X = x) P (X = x)$.

My initial idea goes: $A=(Y\in A) \cup ({X=x})$ such that $x$ partitions $S$.
Then $P(A)=\sum\nolimits_{x\in X} P(Y \in A)P(X=x)$, as $S$ and $S'$ are disjoint, so $P(A)=\sum\nolimits_{x\in X:P(x)>0} P((Y \in A)|X=x))P(X=x)$

Comment: Your proof is correct. What exactly is your doubt?

Comment: Are S and S' really disjoint? And does this mean that X and Y are independent?